# PageSetup problems

Tags: excel, vba, printing, page-setup

In what is hopefully the last problem in the "Print An Individual Range" series of questions, I hereby humbly ask the more knowledgable readers how to copy the PageSetup object from one page to another.

Since you can simply `Dest.PageSetup = Source.PageSetup` I have had to create function that does the same. An abridge form is below:

```
Public Sub CopyPageSetup(ByVal Source As Worksheet, ByRef Dest As Worksheet)
    With Source.PageSetup
        Call SetParam(.AlignMarginsHeaderFooter, Dest.PageSetup.AlignMarginsHeaderFooter)
        ' etc
        Call SetParam(.Zoom, Dest.PageSetup.Zoom)
    End With
End Sub
```

And SetParam is simply:

```
Public Sub SetParam(ByVal Source As Variant, ByRef Dest As Variant)
    If Dest <> Source Then Dest = Source
End Sub
```

However this does not copy the page setup across - immeadiately after calling this function I call `tmp.PrintPreview` (where tmp is a temporary worksheet) and the output is the same as if I had never called the function.

**Is this a mirage (does it work for you?) and if it is not a mirage what do I need to do to correct this?**

Comment: Have you tried recording a Macro, while manually changing the page setup to the configuration that you need?

Answer (score 2):

My version of Excel (2003) doesn't support the .AlignMarginsHeaderFooter property, but I got the zoom and BottomMargin properties to copy to the new page just fine.

```
Public Sub CopyPageSetup(ByVal Source As Worksheet, ByRef Dest As Worksheet)
   With Dest.PageSetup
        .Zoom = Source.PageSetup.Zoom
        .BottomMargin = Source.PageSetup.BottomMargin
   End With
End Sub
```

Comment: It seems to work here, but the problem is that the pages aren't equal. There seems to be something that determines page layout that cannot be copied programmatically.